# Is it a best practice to validate all inputs to a function before using them?

Tags: javascript, validation, user-input

```
function getUserInput(firstName, lastName, callback)  {
    // Do other stuff to validate firstName/lastName here

    // Now save the names
    callback (firstName, lastName);
}
```

I have a function getuserInput, when i call this function and pass in 2 strings and a function, is it a best practice to validate all inputs before using them?

Comment: Maybe reject firstName and lastName if they contain anything other than letters [a-z][A-Z]?

Comment: This really depends on a lot of context. @RedCricket's comment (and answer) isn't really accurate, since names could be all sorts of characters. `신민아` is a valid name, but would fail with that regex. In general, I would rely on _defaulting_ arguments rather than _validating_ them, unless your backend doesn't do any validation. You could default args to empty strings and return early if they're empty or undefined.

Comment: This depends - You should validate inputs, if you expose an API to the outside. If you are writing functions for internal use, you only need to do validation, in case it is likely to trigger on bugs you made, and give you valuable debugging info.

Comment: You might want to check what a [valid name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_name) is first. There is [no real limit](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) what a name can be. Ideally, the only thing you should really be doing is a [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim).

Comment: Yes it depends on context. Like language. How many web sites support supply content in more than one language? The point of my comment is only use minimal set of characters to accomplish whatever it your trying to do.  Its not that complicated.

Answer (score 2):

Validating user input is among best practices in matter of *Software Engineering*, something you should always do as a proficient developer. [See this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/103471/how-should-i-handle-invalid-user-input). However, *how* you do that is more about getting into a **good practice**. Best practices usually change over time, what is considered to be *best* today might not be tomorrow. Event some "bad practices" may be valid in certain contexts. 
Terms like **better** or **best** require a comparison. As per your question example, you probably want to know **when** or **where** in your code should you perform your validation cycle. Instead, you could offer two or more different validation strategies/approaches that you are evaluating and request suggestions about which is the **best fit** for **your current context**.